# SQL Column Numeric to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, numeric

I am trying to convert numeric column (with 13 digits) to DATE and all i can do is this so i can see the date as a string.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(DATEADD(SECOND, Start_Date/1000 ,'1/1/1970')),104)
```

What can i do so this will end up like DATE so i can filter it later?

The database is MS SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression should convert it to a `datetime`:

```
DATEADD(SECOND, Start_Date/1000 , '1970-01-01)
```

If you want a `date`, just convert this to a date:

```
CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, Start_Date/1000 , '1970-01-01') as DATE)
```

Note:  I changed the date format to the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.